# Change Y axis limit in matlab bode plot

Tags: matlab, frequency-analysis

I have measured the frequency response using an accelerometer. Now I want to analyse the data using the FRD object in MATLAB.

When I try to plot the frequency response using MATLAB's bodeplot function and change the y-axis limit of the magnitude plot using ylim, the y-axis limit of both the magnitude and the phase plots change.

Is there any way to change only the y axis limit of the magnitude, while keeping the Y axis limit of the phase unchanged?

Edit:
the question is not related to evaluation of the graphs or their interpretation, but about changing the limits of the a particular axis in the bodeplot. I was looking for a particular function/command in MATLAB.

My question has been perfectly answered by kpg987.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done when creating a handle to the Bode plot. Incidentally, MATLAB provides a pretty good example here already: https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ug/customizing-response-plots-from-the-command-line.html

I've provided a multiple-input, multiple-output (MIMO) system to illustrate how this works. Assuming you already have a system, called `sys_Orig`

```
Handleplot=bodeplot(sys_Orig); %create a handle
p=getoptions(Handleplot); %get the handle options
```

Taking a look at our original Bode plot:

[image]

Suppose I want to now change the top left-hand plot's y-axis limits from [-50 50] to [-100 50], how would I do it? Type in p into the command line to get a peak at adjustable plot parameters:

```
p =
                       Title: [1x1 struct]
                      XLabel: [1x1 struct]
                      YLabel: [1x1 struct]
                   TickLabel: [1x1 struct]
                        Grid: 'off'
                   GridColor: [0.1500 0.1500 0.1500]
                        XLim: {2x1 cell}
                    XLimMode: {2x1 cell}
                        YLim: {4x1 cell}
                    YLimMode: {4x1 cell}
                  IOGrouping: 'none'
                 InputLabels: [1x1 struct]
                OutputLabels: [1x1 struct]
                InputVisible: {2x1 cell}
               OutputVisible: {2x1 cell}
                   FreqUnits: 'rad/s'
                   FreqScale: 'log'
                    MagUnits: 'dB'
                    MagScale: 'linear'
                  MagVisible: 'on'
             MagLowerLimMode: 'auto'
                 MagLowerLim: 0
                  PhaseUnits: 'deg'
                PhaseVisible: 'on'
               PhaseWrapping: 'off'
               PhaseMatching: 'off'
           PhaseMatchingFreq: 0
          PhaseMatchingValue: 0
    ConfidenceRegionNumberSD: 1
```

Notice that Ylim is a 4x1 cell. The 4 is because we have four rows of plots.
  Index the row you'd like to change. In this case, it's our top row, row 1:

```
p.Ylim{1}= [-100 50]; %Setting the y-axis limits
setoptions(Handleplot,p); %update your plot
```

[image]